# How to transform my C# client code into unity c# script

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine

I have this C# client code that recieved data from python script. I want to change this C# script for unity. I have tried many things but every time I run it, it become stuck and nothing happens. I want to show data in textbox and the data inside textbox must be changing with the data we recieved every time continously.
Please tell me what changes do I need to make it compatible with unity 3d?

```
using System; 
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
namespace ClientScript
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //create instance from TCPClient Object
            var client = new TcpClient("192.168.0.102", 10016);
            //var client = new TcpClient("10.120.169.208", 5000);
            

            //if a client has found, the program continues
            Console.WriteLine("client found!");

            //create an instance of the C# Stream class and get the Stream to the client
            var networkStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] encodedBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0");

            //send the drive order to the HDrive
            networkStream.Write(encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.Length);

            //continuously read data comming from the HDrive
            byte[] buffer = new byte[24]; // read in chunks of 85 Byte 
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer));
                encodedBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0");

                //send the drive order to the HDrive
                networkStream.Write(encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First you need a TCP Socket (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream?force_isolation=true&view=net-6.0),  The TCPClient socket is the property client.Client.  Then your while loop has issues.   TCP comes in chunks and you may get zero bytes before you reach end of networkStream due to an underrun.  So loop until you get to EOF.

Comment: It probably runs fine in Unity, but since the code contains an infinite loop, it never gets around to drawing stuff again and thus appears to freeze.